# Laravel return records from relation table

Tags: database, laravel, return, relational-database, record

Hello I want to returned a list of products with the selected category. 
I have two tables connected by relationship table products:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('sn');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->date('warranty');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });

}
```

and table categories:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

product model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function article(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
}

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

And category model:

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I write query SQL in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT
        products.id,
        products.user_id,
        articles.article_name,
        categories.category_name,
        products.sn,
        products.quantity,
        products.warranty,
        products.created_at,
        products.updated_at,
        SUM(quantity) AS ilosc
        FROM
        products
        LEFT JOIN
        categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
        LEFT JOIN
        articles ON products.article_id = articles.id
        GROUP BY articles.article_name
        ORDER BY id;
```

This query works on phpmyadmin but I want write metohod in Laravel. **How can I return a list of products assigned to the selected category ??**  I would add that the selected category is passed in the method show by ID CATEGORY:

```
public function show($id){
    $categories = Category::find($id);

    return view('categories.showcategory', compact('categories'));
}
```

I do not want a solution, only hints how I can do it. I found this theme [enter link description here](http://I%20found%20this,%20but%20still%20do%20not%20know%20how%20to%20do%20it), but still I do not know how to do it ;)

I convert query SQL to query laravel i file CategoriesController:

```
public function show($id){
    $categories = Category::find($id);
    $productsList = DB::table('products')->select('products.id,
    products.user_id,
    articles.article_name,
    categories.category_name,
    products.sn,
    products.quantity,
    products.warranty,
    products.created_at,
    products.updated_at,
    SUM(quantity) AS ilosc')->from('products')->where('id' , '=' , $categories->id)->leftJoin('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->leftJoin('articles', 'products.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')->groupBy('articles.article_name')->orderBy('id')->get();

    return view('categories.showcategory', compact('categories', 'productsList'));
}
```

But Laravel returned error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id, '
>   in 'field list' (SQL: select `products`.`id,` as `` from `products`
>   left join `categories` on `products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
>   left join `articles` on `products`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`
>   where `id` = 1 group by `articles`.`article_name` order by `id` asc)

with the help of swatkins I wrote method:

```
public function show($id){
$categories = Category::find($id);
$productsList = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                  $query->where('category_id', 20);
              }])->get();
return view('categories.showcategory', compact('categories', 'productsList'));
}
```

Laravel returns correctly Products with selected category, but only when I write ID category. In this method ID category is equal to 20.

$query->where('category_id', **20**);

**How can I dynamically pass the value of GET category_id ??**

Answer (score 1):

You already have a category, you just need to eager load the products relationship:

```
public function show($id){
    $categories = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                      $query->where('paid', true);
                  }])->find($id);

    // this will give you a child property on your category 
    // called 'products' that will be an array of associated 
    // Product objects

    return view('categories.showcategory', compact('categories'));
}
```

docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I wrote this method in file CategoriesController: `public function show($id){
    $categories = Category::find($id);
    $products = Category::with('products')->find($id)->get();
    return view('categories.showcategory', compact('categories', 'products'));
    }` And in file showcategory I wrote this foreach loop: `@foreach ($products as $product) 
    {{ $product->products }} 
@endforeach` laravel returns me all the products, and I want to laravel paid only records from the selected category. Category ID is passed in GET.

Comment: You can add filter statements in the `with` call. I've updated my answer with an example. The docs are a bit further down under "Constraining Eager Loads"

Comment: Still return all records from the database, and not only those in the selected category ;( I wrote this: `$products = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                      $query->where('category_id', true);
                  }])->findOrFail($id)->get();` How can I convey to the query id with GET?? I tried this: `...  $query->where('category_id', '=', $categories->id); ...` But Laravel returned **Undefined variable: categories** [link](http://iv.pl/images/76597680607175524685.png)

Comment: You have a one-to-many relationship with products->category -- therefore, you shouldn't have a `category_id` field on your products table. We're gonna need to see more of your setup to be able to help.

Comment: Look when I change number of ID for category_id on 20: `...$query->where('category_id', 19);...` Laravel properly return products only from the category ID=19. Now the question is **How can I dynamically pass the value of GET category_id, instead of 19 ??** Whole: `public function show($id){
    $categories = Category::find($id);
    $products = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                      $query->where('category_id', 19);
                  }])->get();
    return view('categories.showcategory', compact('categories', 'products'));
    }`

Comment: use the Input class:  `$query->where('category_id', Input::get('category_id'))->get();`  --   https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests

Comment: No, It's not work. Laravel returned this: "[]". When I trying this: `    public function show($id){
        $variable = DB::table('products')->where('category_id', Input::get('category_id'))->get();
        return $variable;
    }` Laravel returned []. This method `$products = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) {
                      $query->where('category_id', Input::get('category_id'));
                  }])->get();` This method does not collect ID category with GET

Comment: I'm clearly confused about your process. Could you update your question with more details?

Comment: When I trying  this:`Input::get('category_id'))->get();` Laravel returned empty array: "[]" (It returns nothing). Look: [link](http://iv.pl/images/89745603785404269556.png)

Comment: ...Continue : I want convert this query: `SELECT
  products.id,
  products.user_id,
  articles.article_name,
  categories.category_name,
  products.sn,
  products.quantity,
  products.warranty,
  products.created_at,
  products.updated_at,
  SUM(quantity) AS ilosc
  FROM
  products
  LEFT JOIN
  categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
  LEFT JOIN
  articles ON products.article_id = articles.id
        where products.category_id = 19
  GROUP BY articles.article_name
  ORDER BY id;` to Laravel method [link](http://iv.pl/images/59143483053537816756.png)